# Find first and last object in has_many through assosiation by given id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

First of all I'm rails beginner, please don't through tomatoes at me :)
I have models:

```
class RailwayStation < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :trains, foreign_key: :current_station_id
  has_many :railway_stations_routes
  has_many :routes, through: :railway_stations_routes
end

class Route < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :railway_stations_routes
  has_many :trains
  has_many :railway_stations, through: :railway_stations_routes
end

class RailwayStationsRoute < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :railway_station
  belongs_to :route
end

class Train < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :current_station, class_name: 'RailwayStation', foreign_key: :current_station_id
  belongs_to :route
  has_many :tickets
  has_many :wagons
end
```

For example station_from = 1 and station_last = 9
Now i need to find all Trains that follow the route. In the route i need  conditions:

- `railway_station.first.id = station_from`
- `railway_station.last.id = station_last`

I know that i need to use joins.where but don't know how...

***UPDATE***
This code works but I think there is a much better solution:

```
routes_from = Route.joins(:railway_stations).where('railway_stations.id': 1)
routes_to = Route.joins(:railway_stations).where('railway_stations.id': 2)
routes_from.each do |route_from|
  routes_to.where(id: route_from).each do |route|
    route.trains.each do |train|
      @trains ||= []
      @trains << train
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: ``Train.includes(:route).select{|tr| tr.route.railway_stations.map(&:id).include?(station_from) &&  tr.route.railway_stations.map(&:id).include?(station_last)} ``

Comment: I'm not sur but you can test.

Comment: gives error like undefined method `railway_stations' for nil:NilClass

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you want to sort railway stations inside route relation. I think you need to add numbers to `RailwayStationsRoute` for sorting.

In general you can do like this:

```
rw_from = RaillwayStation.find(1)
rw_to = RaillwayStation.find(2)
trains = Train.where(route: rw_from.routes & rw_to.routes)
```